# UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, appium

Trying to launch the third party emulator Genymotion via Appium 1.3.4.1. But it fails.

I have done the following things.

I disable the Launch AVD from appium and launching the Genymotion AVD through the code.

I paste the overall code here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecuteException, IOException {

        String deviceName = "Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920";


        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, ""); 
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920"); 
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app","D:/SOFTWARES/Apks/Hybrid.apk");

        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
        CommandLine launchEmul = new CommandLine("C:/Program Files/Genymobile/Genymotion/player");
        launchEmul.addArgument("--vm-name");
        launchEmul.addArgument("\""+deviceName+"\"");
        executor.setExitValue(1);
        executor.execute(launchEmul, resultHandler);
        Thread.sleep(40);

        driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

    }
```

I couldn't able to start the Emulator through the code.
Suggestions please.

Comment: @IdanE Yes, I used the command line arguments to start the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below command line arguments to start the genymotion emulator

```
 CommandLine launchEmul = new CommandLine("Genymotion player path");
 launchEmul.addArgument("--vm-name");
 launchEmul.addArgument("\""+deviceName+"\"");
 executor.setExitValue(1);
 executor.execute(launchEmul, resultHandler);
```